# How to load a local html file inside an iframe in my react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, iframe

I'm having troubles when trying to load a html file from my public folder in a React application created with **create-react-app**. Am I missing a config setting somewhere in webpack?

I currently have this folder structure:

[image]

And I want to show the test.html file inside an Iframe in my React component like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const Component = props => {
  return (<iframe src="/test/index.html"title="Docuvieware" />);
};

export default Component;
```

But this is giving me a "Cannot GET /test/index.html" in the Iframe. Also when surfing directly to **http://localhost:3000/test/index.html** I get a white page that says 'Cannot GET /test/index.html'

I also tried to use **"process.env.PUBLIC_URL"** inside my component but this was undefined.

Comment: `http://localhost:3000/test/index.html` what about that?

Comment: this redirects me to a white page that says "Cannot GET /test/index.html"

Comment: If you just need this page for testing your iframe, i suggest to use react-router and just create route for it in your app... I was testing my iframe this way.

Comment: you do not need extra setting for iframe. look like publicpath is not resolved. try to usie "/public/test/index.html" If not update the cra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this by using **CopyWebpackPlugin**.
Just added the test folder in my src folder, and then added the following line to my webpack config:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'src/test', to: 'test' }]),
```

and then /test/index.html gave the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest version of the code might look like it.

In the webpack config do next.

```
const path = require('path');
paths.root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
paths.publicFiles = path.join(paths.root, 'public');
paths.test = path.join(paths.publicFiles, 'test');

plugins: [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { path.join(paths.test, 'index.html'), to: 'src/test-frame.html' }
  ])
]
```

then in your component use the next lines (change localhost if needed):

```
<iframe
  src="http://localhost:3000/src/test-frame.html"
  id="unique-id"
  title="Frame test"
  // remove these styles later
  style={{ minHeight: `50vh`, width: '100vw' }}
/>
```